# Why do Mediterranean main currents surrounding landmasses turn counter-clockwise?

Tags: oceanography, ocean-currents, coriolis

At North Hemisphere, main superficial currents turn clock-wise, because of [Coriolis Effect](https://scijinks.gov/coriolis/).

I would expect on Mediterranean Sea to have currents turning in the same sense, but, surrounding landmasses, this picture shows a counter-clockwise sense of rotation.

> [image]
>
> Source: [researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Map-of-the-Mediterranean-Sea-with-the-name-of-the-sub-basins-main-currents-white-lines_fig1_316850029)

Why so?

Comment: here is a "live map" of the area https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/ocean/surface/currents/orthographic=16.23,38.15,3000

Comment: @trond hansen nice map. with a more detail I see how the Stratit of Gibraltar's current is partialy forced by Coriolis to go throw the North. But I still see counter-clockwise currents when they are paralel to the coastline.

Comment: i wonder if this might have something to do with colder atlantic water entering the mediterranian and the elevated salinity in the area.

Comment: You have to distinguish between general circulation and eddies. You clearly have both cyclonic and anticyclonic eddies in the Mediterranean. In terms of general circulation, the main effects are wind-driven and baroclinic flows. In the Mediterranean the dominating factor is baroclinicity with denser waters in the center of the basins that forces a general anticyclonic flow. http://tornado.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m407_707/Monteverdi/Satellite/Oceanography/eddy.htm & https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/1755876X.2010.11020116

Comment: @arkaia What about the effect of centrifugal force on mesoscale eddies ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a centrifugal force. There is the Coriolis effect due to the rotation of Earth (planetary vorticity), the relative vorticity due to stretching, the baroclinic torque, and inertia.

Comment: @arkaia But there is a centrifugal force in NS - http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Navier-StokesEquationsRotational.html. If you assume a gradient wind relation the centrifugal force is included with the Coriolis as seen in this paper -https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1029/JC090iC03p04911

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109500/does-centrifugal-force-exist Both Centrifugal and Coriolis forces are effects that are better described as effects rather than forces. While I understand that many NS explanations include then in the RHS (as forces), in reality inertia and a Coriolis effect are better describers

Comment: @arkaia If we take cyclones as an analogy why  mesoscale eddies do not exclusively turn counter clockwise in NH ? Or cyclones are a very poor analogy with mesoscale eddies ?

Comment: mesoscale eddies tend to rotate depending on the density in the center of the eddy. Take the Gulf Stream rings as an example. Cold core rings have a denser center and flow counterclockwise, warm core rings have a lighter core and flow clockwise: https://marine.coastal.edu/gulfstream/p6.htm

Comment: @arkaia so the analogy with tropical cyclones is a poor one ? Can you bring in a NS perspective (using balance conditions) why they turn clockwise and counterclockwise.